# Can a value of cookie be an array? can I pass it as an array? php?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I'm doing something like this, and it doesn't seem to work!

```
<?php 
    //cookie for saving recently viewed products list
    //global $post;
    //echo $post->ID;
    if (!$_COOKIE['mediSHOPrecentlyViewedlist']) {
        setcookie("mediSHOPrecentlyViewedlist", $post->ID, strtotime('+6 days'), "/");
    } else {
        $cookie_value = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['mediSHOPrecentlyViewedlist']);
        $cookie_value = explode(",",$cookie_value);
        array_unshift($cookie_value, $post->ID);
        setcookie("mediSHOPrecentlyViewedlist", $cookie_value, strtotime('+6 days'), "/");

        print_r($cookie_value);
    }
?>
```

$cookie_value is an array. Is this possible?

Comment: eplode will produce an array. So yes, it is possible

Comment: well this part setcookie("mediSHOPrecentlyViewedlist", $cookie_value, strtotime('+6 days'), "/"); of the script doesn't work. if I put something else a string cookie is set if not old cookie remains.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it can, but you should consider the following:

Cookies are meant to store minimal data because the can be altered by the user. Storing a lot of data here is NOT secure. You should store userid, password-hash and minor important stuff, and let your scrips take care of the rest.

However, if you want to store the array, an idea might be to `json_encode` the data before storing it and `json_decode` and content when grabbing it.

Comment: I like this option as well

Comment: @JohnConde: `serialize` works great too. Just two sides of the same coin. Important to note the fact that this is not secure tho.

Answer (score 1):

[`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array:

```
array_unshift($cookie_value, $post->ID);
$cookie_value = serialize($cookie_value);
```

Then to read it's value, [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it:

```
$cookie_value = unserialize($_COOKIE['mediSHOPrecentlyViewedlist']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You nees to `serialize()` it and `unserialize()` it.